# Pycharm-Find Bottlenecks function

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm

I want to find bottleneck function in python script. that would be better if I could do it with IDE's feature. (I am using PyCharm now)

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

**CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+N** allows you to go to symbols, quite powerful because you can search at the same time function names, class names, packages and so

You can always rely too on **CTRL+SHIFT+F** to find in your whole project (script in this case) and you'll get a nice preview of the usage

Comment: I want to find performance bottleneck function! not function named "Bottleneck"!!

Comment: Then better take a look about python profiling, it will help you determine the slowest points in your code
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956112/how-to-determine-bottlenecks-in-code-besides-visual-inspection

Comment: @A.Romeu your link is broken